# How to use InputStream and OutputStream on the Event thread

Tags: blackberry, thread-safety

I am new to blackberry development and I am creating a native blackberry application. On every screen of my application, I need to send and receive data to the server on the same connection.

What I have done so far is I have made a `ConnectToServer` class which has a bunch of methods for sending and receiving. I instantiate it on the main screen and I pass it to each screen as a parameter.

That class in not a thread because I only read and write when the user types in information and presses a button. So basically I am using the inputStream and outputStream on the event thread which I hear is **BAD**. Then I ask `ConnectToServer` to get me what the server sent. For instance, I get a vector which I use to make a ListField.

How can I make these UI updates?

```java
public class Screen3 extends MainScreen {

  ConnectToServer con;
  Vector v;

  public Screen3(String exerciseName, ConnectToServer connect)
  {
      con = connect;
      con.send(exerciseName);
      v = con.receiveVector();

      mylist = new listField();
      mylist.setSize(v.size());
      add(mylist);
   }

   public void drawListRow(...)
   {
      graphics.drawText((String) v.elementAt(index)
   }
}
```

Comment: you get the vector (v) from the server ?.

Comment: you want to display the values in vector v ?

Comment: No I want to use the Vector I get to update a ListField

Comment: where you adding the LidtField ?

Comment: Sorry about the poor code editing... Thanks for fixing it just now...

Comment: I don't have a good enough reputation to chat... Maybe you could facebook me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there's many ways to approach this.  First of all, since it seems like you only want one instance of `ConnectToServer`, and you are currently having to pass that around, you might try making that class a [Singleton object](http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-singleton-design-pattern).  This is not necessary, and does not have anything to do with your **threading** problem, but I only offer it as a solution, for situations where you want to enforce that there's only **one** instance of something, and want to avoid having to pass it around everywhere.  A simple Singleton implementation might be this:

```java
public class ConnectToServer {

    private static ConnectToServer _instance;

    /** use this static method to get the one and only instance */
    public static ConnectToServer getInstance() {
        if (_instance == null) {
            _instance = new ConnectToServer();
        }
        return _instance;
    }

    /** private to enforce Singleton pattern */
    private ConnectToServer() {
    }
}
```

And use it in your screens like this (no need to pass it into the constructor any more):

```java
ConnectoToServer connection = ConnectToServer.getInstance();
connection.blahBlahBlah();
```

Now, on to the threading problem.  You're right that you should not be performing network requests on the main (aka "UI", aka "Event") thread.  If you have a nice separate `ConnectToServer` class, that makes it easier to encapsulate this behaviour.  Instead of UI clients using a *synchronous* `send()` and `receiveVector()` method, make one method that just kicks off the request, and another callback method that the `ConnectToServer` class will call when the response comes back.  The `ConnectToServer` class will use a `Thread` to perform this work, and thus avoid freezing the UI during the request.

I'll define an `interface` that the UI clients will implement:

```java
public interface RequestListener {

    /** listeners must implement this method to get data.  method will be called on the UI thread */
    void onDataReceived(Vector response);
}
```

And then the new (partial) `ConnectToServer` class:

```java
public class ConnectToServer {
    private Thread _worker;
    private RequestListener _listener;

    public void setRequestListener(RequestListener listener) {
        // note: this implementation only allows one listener at once.  
        //  make it a list if you need something more
        _listener = listener;
    }

    /** initiate a network request on a background thread */
    public void sendRequest(final String request) {
        _worker = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {    // run on the background/worker thread
                send(request);

                final Vector response = receiveVector();

                if (_listener != null) {
                    // this assumes all our listeners are UI objects, so we pass 
                    //   data back to them  on the UI thread:
                    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {    // run on UI thread                
                            _listener.onDataReceived(response);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        _worker.start();
    }
}
```

Note that you should also make your **original** `send()` and `receiveVector()` methods in this class `private`.  They should only be called from *inside* the class now, not directly from UI clients.

Then, you need to code your `Screen` classes like this:

```java
public class Screen3 extends MainScreen implements RequestListener {

    public Screen3(String exerciseName) {
        ConnectToServer connection = ConnectToServer.getInstance();
        connection.setRequestListener(this);
        // kick off the request (on a background thread)
        connection.sendRequest(exerciseName);
    }

    public void onDataReceived(Vector response) {
         if (mylist == null) {
             // first time data has been received, so create and add the list field:
             mylist = new listField();            
             add(mylist);
         }
         mylist.setSize(response.size());
         // TODO: presumably, you would copy the contents of 'response' into 'mylist' here  
    }
}
```

Also, you might also want to code the server class to protect against multiple UI clients making *concurrent* requests, allow current requests to be cancelled, etc.  But the above should get you started on a solution that provides a responsive app, without freezing your UI.

Comment: Good answer, it shows how to make a request asynchronously. But I think using a Singleton instance for making connection will limit the ability to sending concurrent requests. Though I didn't understand the sentence `I need to send and receive data to the server on the same connection` well, I think it is about using the same URL, not the same Connection instance.

Comment: Thank you, Nate, for your answer! You are such a helpful person! I will use the Singleton instance because I am going to use the same connection instance because that makes more sense to me. Does it make sense to you? Or should I just keep making new connections?

Comment: @user1498739, that really depends on how you want your app to work.  I don't know what kinds of interactions you're using the network request for.  Does it make sense for multiple of these interactions to be allowed at once?  Or, do they fundamentally need to be issued one at a time?  Should the user be able to start a new request before the previous one has completed (without cancelling the original one)?  So, it depends.  You might need to post a new question *just about the issue of one vs. multiple connections*.  But, in general, using one connection can certainly be a valid design.